# How do we fix the inability to run test cases in Gitpod?

Tags: gitpod

I am unable to test my code in Gitpod.
The flask icon in the bottom left is not appearing; and, I'm unable to run test cases.

How may I correct this?

I tried disabling any possible extensions to be able to run test cases...but nothing seems to work.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try opening your Gitpod workspace in VSCode Desktop client to see if it works there:

- https://www.gitpod.io/docs/references/ides-and-editors/vscode

Comment: Hi. Actually, removing gitpod extensions helped.  Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling unecessary extensions helped.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).